# Using React js, how can a dropdown menu attribute be changed?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, onchange

A few people on a React discord channel were trying to figure out how to change an attribute for a selected "item" in a Dropdown menu.

The basic logic seemed to be to have an onChange, which involved the useState/refs/etc, but ...

If anyone has any pointers, or sample code, this would be appreciated!

Thanks